# How to force BinaryReader to read this array correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, endianness

I have a byte array, received from java application via network. 
I need to parse this array correctly. The format is as follow:

```
int - first for bytes
int - next for bytes
string - rest of data.
```

Take a look at this [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3055964/cs.gif).
As you can see, the first four bytes is `0, 0, 0, 1`. The actual integer value should be `1`, but when I read it through `BinaryReader.ReadInt32`, I receive `16777216`. I doubt this has something to do with byte endianness (but could be wrong), but I don't know how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's an endian issue. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294659/c-sharp-big-endian-ulong-from-4-bytes) has examples of how to reverse the byte-order of integer types